# ng-select error in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with a coloumn gender .it is set by default from database when form is loaded.
but when i click edit button a drop down will appear with genders 'male' and 'female' but the default value is missing.

here is the code

```
<td data-title="'<?php echo $this->lang->line('label_gender'); ?>'" sortable="'gender'" filter="{ 'gender': 'text' }">
   <span ng-if="!staff_reg.$edit">{{staff_reg.gender}}</span>
   <div ng-if="staff_reg.$edit">
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="staff_reg.gender">
         <option value="male" ng-selected="staff_reg.gender=='male'" ><?php echo $this->lang->line('label_male'); ?></option>
         <option value="female" ng-selected="staff_reg.gender=='female'"><?php echo $this->lang->line('label_female'); ?></option>
      </select>
   </div>
</td>
```

Comment: staff_reg.gender=='male/female' should be staff_reg.gender='male/female' (one equal sign) in ng-selected.. does that fix it? Or are you asking something else? Sorry, I'm not sure what default value you're referring to.

Comment: no .it is comparison.== is used.

Comment: Are you sure of the value of `staff_reg.gender` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be perfectly fine. Kindly cross verify it with this working fiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/dakra/U3pVM/

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl" >

    <span>{{greeting}}</span>
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="staff_reg.gender">
         <option value="male" ng-selected="staff_reg.gender=='male'" >Male</option>
         <option value="female" ng-selected="staff_reg.gender=='female'">Female</option>
      </select>


    <span>{{staff_reg.gender}}</span>

   </div>
</div>


function TodoCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.greeting = "Hello";
    $scope.staff_reg = {gender : 'female'};
}
```